# How to loop through one element of a zip() function twice - Python

Tags: python, image, loops, resize, zip

So here's my dilema... I'm writing a script that reads all .png files from a folder and then converts them to a number of different dimensions which I have specified in a list. Everything works as it should except it quits after handling one image.

Here is my code:

```
sizeFormats = ["1024x1024", "114x114", "40x40", "58x58", "60x60", "640x1136", "640x960"]

def resizeImages():

widthList = []
heightList = []
resizedHeight = 0
resizedWidth = 0

#targetPath is the path to the folder that contains the images
folderToResizeContents = os.listdir(targetPath)

#This splits the dimensions into 2 separate lists for height and width (ex: 640x960 adds
#640 to widthList and 960 to heightList
for index in sizeFormats:
    widthList.append(index.split("x")[0])
    heightList.append(index.split("x")[1])

#for every image in the folder, apply the dimensions from the populated lists and save
for image,w,h in zip(folderToResizeContents,widthList,heightList):
    resizedWidth = int(w)
    resizedHeight = int(h)
    sourceFilePath = os.path.join(targetPath,image)
    imageFileToConvert = Image.open(sourceFilePath)
    outputFile = imageFileToConvert.resize((resizedWidth,resizedHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    outputFile.save(sourceFilePath)
```

The following will be returned if the target folder contains 2 images called image1.png,image2.png (for sake of visualization I'll add the dimensions that get applied to the image after an underscore):

image1_1024x1024.png,
..............,
image1_640x690.png (Returns all 7 different dimensions for image1 fine)

it stops there when I need it to apply the same transformations to image_2. I know this is because the length of widthList and heightList are only 7 elements long and so exits the loop before image2 gets its turn. Is there any way I can go about looping through widthList and heightList for every image in the targetPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not keep it simple:

```
for image in folderToResizeContents:
    for fmt in sizeFormats:
        (w,h) = fmt.split('x')
```

**N.B. You are overwriting the files produced as you are not changing the name of the outpath.**

Comment: That's helpful for getting the widths and heights separated but it doesn't help solve the real issue I'm having which is getting those attributes affixed to each image in the target folder

Comment: Ah, I am indeed overwriting the files! Added in a little tidbit to generate unique names and it's working as expected. Thanks a lot for your input I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Nest your for loops and you can apply all 7 dimensions to each image

```
for image in folderToResizeContents:
    for w,h in zip(widthList,heightList):
```

the first for loop will ensure it happens for each image, whereas the second for loop will ensure that the image is resized to each size

Comment: I tried nesting it, but when you do it this way every image takes the last dimension of the list (640x960)

Comment: @ColeGoodyear it shouldn't, that means you're setting it up wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-iterate through the sizeFormats for every file. Zip doesn't do this unless you get even trickier with cyclic iterators for height and width.

Sometimes tools such as zip make for longer more complicated code when a couple of nested for loops work fine. I think its more straight forward than splitting into multiple lists and then zipping them back together again.

```
sizeFormats = ["1024x1024", "114x114", "40x40", "58x58", "60x60", "640x1136", "640x960"]
sizeTuples = [(int(w), int(h)) for w,h in map(lambda wh: wh.split('x'), sizeFormats)]

def resizeImages():

    #for every image in the folder, apply the dimensions from the populated lists and save
    for image in os.listdir(targetPath):
        for resizedWidth, resizedHeight in sizeTuples:
            sourceFilePath = os.path.join(targetPath,image)
            imageFileToConvert = Image.open(sourceFilePath)
            outputFile = imageFileToConvert.resize((resizedWidth,resizedHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            outputFile.save(sourceFilePath)
```

Comment: When I run this I run into the same problem as when I try Stephan's code below. Every image takes on the last dimension of the list so I end up with 7 images for each input .png that are all 640x960

Comment: I was focused on the iteration part... see @Steve Barnes answer also. `outputFile.save(sourceFilePath)` keeps overwriting your files (in fact, you overwrote your original input file). You need to generate unique names, perhaps by appending the sizeFormats string to the file.

Comment: Ah you're a saint, I can't believe I overlooked that! Added in a little tidbit to generate unique names and it's working as expected. Thanks gor your help